# CKEditor Can't install emoji plugin

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, emoji

I can't install emoji plugin correctly with CKEditor 4.
I follow the documentation and install dependancies too.
Emoji seems to be here somewhere but it is not displayed in the toolbar.

Notice I use django-ckeditor but that works the same.
There is no error in log console from my browser.

Here is my config :

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        # 'toolbar': 'full',
        'codeSnippet_theme': 'monokai_sublime',
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', 'RemoveFormat', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
            ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll'],
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript'],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', '-',
                'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
                       'Language'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink'],
            ['Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'CodeSnippet', 'Code'],
            ['emoji', 'SpecialChar', 'Youtube'],
            ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'],
            ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
            ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks'],
        ],
        'extraPlugins': 'codesnippet,youtube,codeTag,emoji',
        'removePlugins': 'flash,anchor,iframe,forms,div,exportpdf,templates',
        'removeButtons': 'Anchor',
        'width': '100%',
        'tabSpaces': 4,
    }
}
```

Notice that youtube, codeTag and codesnippet work perfectly and I do the same for emoji which doesn't work.

Please, someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh god I solved my problem just by replacing `'emoji'` by `'EmojiPanel'` in configs.
It is not mentioned anywhere and I found it in the `plugin.js` of emoji plugin.
This is too weird that no website documentation mention it...